# backing up and compressing /home directory using lzma

Tags: command-line, tar, compression

Will this work?

```
sudo tar -cvpf backboxhome.tar.gz/home/user --lzma
```

I am mainly confused on where to place the `--lzma` argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `--lzma` argument will work if you put it there but you have problems elsewhere.

You need to put space between `backboxhome.tar.gz/home/user`, also you are creating a `lzma` compressed archive, not a gzipped one so rename the `backboxhome.tar.gz` to e.g. `backboxhome.tar.lzma` (it would be ok if you name it as `gz` but you would get a hard time remembering what it is really and also while extarcting).

Your command as a whole could take the form:

```
sudo tar -cvpf backboxhome.tar.lzma /home/user --lzma
```

Although a better practice is to use the options one after another:

```
sudo tar --lzma -cvpf backboxhome.tar.lzma /home/user
```

Note that `lzma` and `xz` both uses the same compression algorithm, in fact `lzma` is deprecated in favor of the newer `xz`. So you would be better off using `xz` (`tar -J`):

```
sudo tar -cvpJf backboxhome.tar.xz /home/user
```